# Visibility binding to ListboxItems inside template

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, listbox, datatemplate

I'm trying to change the `Visibility` of elements inside a `ListBoxItem` by clicking on a `CheckBox` outside the `ListBox` which contains Items, but it doesn't seem to work.

It looks like the the binding doesn't work inside the `ListBoxItems`.

I'm using a template for my items

XAML

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="ShotTemplate">
        <Grid x:Name="GridItem" Width="200">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <TextBox x:Name="ShotBox" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Description}" Visibility="{Binding EditMode, ElementName=EditMode, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="ShotBlock" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Description}" Visibility="{Binding EditMode, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=False }" />                            
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>

<ListBox Name="ShotList" ItemsSource="{Binding AllShotsCollection}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ShotTemplate}"/>

<CheckBox Name="EditMode" IsChecked="{Binding EditMode}" Content="Edit Mode" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,30,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

</Grid>
```

ViewModel

```
private bool _editMode = true;
public bool EditMode
{
    get { return _editMode; }
    set { _editMode = value; RaisePropertyChanged("EditMode"); }
}
```

How do I change `ShotBox` and `ShotBlock` `Visibility` by checking or unchecking the `CheckBox`. I know the converter works correctly, that's not the problem it must have something to do with the binding.

Answer (score 0):

The ElementName binding scope is within the template only. I would define an attached property on the *ListView* (not the ListViewItem) and have the Checkbox toggle that property. Within the DataTemplate, you'll be able to use RelativeSource / FindAncestor binding to find the ListView.

Answer (score 0):

This line of xaml code is not working. You are trying to bind to the view element and viewmodel prop. at the same time.

```
<TextBox x:Name="ShotBox" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Description}" Visibility="{Binding EditMode, ElementName=EditMode, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
```

Remove this 'ElementName=EditMode' so that it would bind properly to the viewmodel property 'EditMode'. 
OR if you want to bind to the view element only use

```
Visibility="{Binding Path=IsChecked, ElementName=EditMode, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
```